# Golang - 0 not as null

Tags: struct, go

I am passing values to a struct in which the value has `omitempty`

`Offset     uint64 'json:"offset,omitempty"'`

However when I pass 0 as the value of offset it is also omitted.

Can I somehow declare 0 as a value which is not defined as null?

Answer (score 6):

Structures for serialization often use pointer to indicate a nullable field. It can make working with the structure a little more cumbersome to work with, but has the advantage of discerning between `nil` and `0`

```
type T struct {
    Offset *uint64 `json:"offset,omitempty"`
}
```

With a nil pointer

```
t := T{}
// marshals to "{}"
```

And after allocating a zero value

```
t.Offset = new(uint64)
// marshals to `{"offset":0}`
```

Comment: @Elliot Reeve You should also look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998222/json-parsing-of-int64-in-go-null-values)